# How to download audio result from converting text to speech using Speech Synthesis?

Tags: html5-audio, text-to-speech, audio-recording, speech-synthesis, google-text-to-speech

I'm using Speech Synthesis ([Web Speech API](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/speechapi.html)) to convert text to speech, but I can't figure how to download produced audio. I thought about using recorder.js, but hope there is easier process to access it.

For better illustration - [IBM Watson Text-to-speech](http://text-to-speech-demo.mybluemix.net/) offers audio download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there's no way to do this as of now. Even recorder.js won't let you do that. The issue is that the web speech api and the web audio api don't play nicely together. Speech generated from the web speech api goes right to your speakers, and you don't get any opportunity to re-route it elsewhere.

Comment: btw I believe that the IBM example is using proprietary IBM technology, not the web speech api.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Then I can't use web speech api. Do you know any open source text to speech with the audio download capability ?

Comment: I don't know of any open source tech that does what you want, sorry =/